# Why is there an episode 1A and 1B on Crunchyroll?

Tags: re-zero, crunchyroll

I'm starting the series Re: Zero on [Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/rezero-starting-life-in-another-world-) and I noticed theres an episode 1A and 1B, what is this about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a [twitter post](https://twitter.com/s3nsi/status/716737246662148096?lang=en) answering this exact same question and it appears that Crunchyroll merely split the one-hour episode in two parts. You should start with A, then continue to B, and then continue chronologically.

Answer (score 0):

Episode 1 is an extended 50-minute episode, which is double the length of a typical anime episode. So they split it into two parts, so that both parts would be the length of one episode.

Comment: The existing answer from three years ago already says basically the same thing. I don't see what this adds.